# Integration of $\ln(\sqrt{x})$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to integrate:
$$\int\ln(\sqrt{x})dx$$

I'm applying:
$$udv=uv-\int vdu$$

so i set: $u=ln(\sqrt x)$, $du=\frac{1}{2x}$ and $v=dx , dv=x$

So :
$$\ln(\sqrt{x})x-\int\frac{1}{2x}dx$$ and my final result is:
$$\ln(\sqrt{x})x-\frac{1}{2}\ln(|x|)$$

Seeing the graph i think it's not correct. Where's the error?

Comment: You should have gotten $dv = dx$ and $v = x$, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have $u=\ln(\sqrt{x})$, $du = \frac{1}{2x}\color{red}{dx}$, $dv = \color{red}{dx}$, and $v=\color{red}{x}$.  Notice that a differential needs to equal a differential.

Then you get $$uv-\int v\ du = \ln(\sqrt{x})x - \int \frac{x}{2x}dx = \ln(\sqrt{x})x - \int \frac{1}{2}dx$$

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is that $v$ is **not** $dx$; rather $dv = dx$ and $v = x$.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind:

$$\ln(\sqrt{x})=\frac{\ln(x)}{2}.$$

Now we find:

$$\int \frac{\ln(x)}{2} dx.$$

using integration by parts.

Let $u=\ln(x), dv=\frac{1}{2} dx,$ so we have $v=\frac{x}{2}, du=\frac{1}{x} dx$

Then we have by integration by parts:

$$\int u dv= uv - \int v du.$$

Plugging everything in, we have:

$$\ln(x)\frac{x}{2} -\int \frac{x}{2} \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) dx,$$

which equals

$$\ln(x)\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x}{2} +C, $$

where $C$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out that parts can be avoided by use of a log rule. The integrand is $\ln(\sqrt{x})=\ln(x^{1/2})=(1/2)\ln(x),$ so one can finish using the antiderivative for $\ln(x),$ which I recall is $x \ln x -x.$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that integration by parts is the right way of seeing that the antiderivative of $\log(x)$ is $x \log(x) - x$. So the argument does not really change...

Comment: I agree with Ashvin.

Comment: While integration by parts is the way to show this one time, I can see where Coffeemath comes from. I also remember this (and a bunch of other integrals) by heart. Whenever I have to do this problem again for my students, it's like "O man, here we go again...", but they of course have not seen it before....

Comment: I agree with Inranfat, and was thinking of the integral of $\ln x$ as one of those "basic" rules like integral of $\cos x$ is $\sin x.$